# al iniciar el servicio de apache2 me da error

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

estoy realizando una práctica de apache2 esta me pedia que cambiara entre otras cosas en el fichero security los atributos ServerSignature dejandolo en off, al apagar el servicio de apache2 y volverlo a encender me da error .
Dejo en una captura  el systemctl status del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]
este seria el archivo ports.conf el cual dice que hay error de sintaxis

Comment: Hay un error de sintaxis en tu archivo `ports.conf`. ¿Puedes pegar el contenido del archivo?

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata he añadido una captura para que lo veas , gracias .

Comment: Te falta un espacio entre "NameVirtualHost" y el asterisco.